# Trouble understanding scope of Prototype Class

Tags: javascript, function, class, prototype, createjs

I'm currently writing a Scene structure for a game I'm making in javascript with the createjs framework. The problem I'm running into is properly referencing the original class in the prototypal functions. I'm relatively new to javascript and this is the first time I've had to use prototype. My current code is as follows:

```
function Intro(p, c){
    this.parent = p;
    var s = new createjs.Stage(c);
    this.stage = s;

    this.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    this.queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    this.queue.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete);
    this.queue.loadManifest([{id:"bg", src:"images/Intro/intro_background.png"}]);
}
Intro.prototype.handleComplete = function(event){
    console.log("queue completed - handling...");
    var q = event.target;
    var bg = new createjs.Bitmap(q.getResult("bg"));
    this.stage.addChild(bg);
    this.stage.update();
}
```

When I get to

> this.stage.addChild(bg);

it appears to lose scope and I get "cannot call method 'addChild' of undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-xv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you invoke function in JS, it'll be bound dynamically. What value will be bound to the `this` depends on the way you invoke it, whether function is called as a constructor and whether your code is running in strict mode.

In your case, the following line:

```
this.queue.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete);
```

makes your function to run with `this` bound to the global object (in the web browser, global object is a `window` object) or, if in strict mode, `this` will be undefined.

As @dystroy suggested, use `bind()` method to change this behaviour. Calling:

```
this.queue.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete.bind(this));
```

causes binding `this` inside the `handleComplete()` to the same `this` as in `Intro`.

---

If you want to understand it in more detail. I strongly suggest reading [Dmitry Soshnikov's blog](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your scope problem by changing

```
this.queue.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete);
```

to

```
this.queue.addEventListener("complete", this.handleComplete.bind(this));
```

so that the scope of the bound function is `this`.

BTW, you might be interested by my game in which I override createjs classes ( https://github.com/Canop/SpaceBullet/tree/master/src ). I think I handled this problem in a clean way.

Comment: If need less than internet explorer 9 compatibility, then maybe take a look at jQueries .proxy(). It does the same thing.

Comment: As he uses createjs I doubt he worries about compatibility with IE8.

Comment: thanks a ton, i'll definitely look into how you handled things in your game!